# Unable to make use color coded text in sales force lightning Calendar

Tags: lightning, calendar

How can I make this "null" text different color in salesforce lightning calendar. I tried with formula 
field but it is not working. I tried with image function to show a image but html tag does not escape.
Could any one help me how I will be able to achieve this?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to achieve your goals. You'd have to write a custom component to get the desired results.

Comment: How can I refer the custom components in calendar?

Comment: @User_stack You wouldn't put a custom component in a calendar, you'd write a custom calendar and put it on a Flexipage.